# How can I access variable in switch case outside of switch block?

Tags: apex, database, switch-case

I am trying to upsert a dynamic sObject list of records using Database.Upsert, I want to be able to use AllOrNone parameter however this returns an error saying that my `toUpsert` variable must be a concrete sObject.

This is my code which brings up that concrete error:

```
    List<sObject> toUpsert = (List<sObject>)Type.ForName('List<' + objectName  + '>').newInstance();
    for(sObject dynObject : lstObjects) {
        toUpsert.add(dynObject);
    }
    system.debug(toUpsert);
    Database.UpsertResult[] up = Database.upsert(toUpsert, f, false);
```

The problem is as this needs to be dynamic I'm stuck how this can be dynamic enough to do upsert the records, I've figured using switch statements would be the half way solution here but it compalins that the upsert variable is not available on my Database.upsert line.

Code for half way solution:

```
        Schema.SObjectField f = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(objectName).getDescribe().fields.getMap().get(extKey);

    switch on objectName {
        when 'Account' {
            List<Account> toUpsert = (List<Account>)Type.ForName('List<' + objectName  + '>').newInstance();
            for(sObject dynObject : (List<Account>)lstObjects) {
                toUpsert.add(dynObject);
            }
        }
        when 'Address__c' {
            List<Address__c> toUpsert = (List<Address__c>)Type.ForName('List<' + objectName  + '>').newInstance();
            for(sObject dynObject : (List<Address__c>)lstObjects) {
                toUpsert.add(dynObject);
            }

        }
    }

    Database.UpsertResult[] up = Database.upsert(toUpsert, f, false);
    system.debug(toUpsert);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just put the `upsert` inside your `when` blocks.

```
List<Database.UpsertResult> results;
switch on objectName {
    when 'Account' {
        List<Account> toUpsert = new List<Account>();
        toUpsert.addAll(dynamicRecords);
        results = Database.upsert(toUpsert, externalIdField, /*allOrNone*/false);
    }
    when 'Address__c' {
        List<Address__c> toUpsert = new List<Address__c>();
        toUpsert.addAll(dynamicRecords);
        results = Database.upsert(toUpsert, externalIdField, /*allOrNone*/false);

    }
}
system.debug(results);
```

If casting works, you can even one line these blocks.

```
List<Database.UpsertResult> results;
switch on objectName {
    when 'Account' {
        results = Database.upsert((List<Account>)toUpsert, externalIdField, /*allOrNone*/false);
    }
    when 'Address__c' {
        results = Database.upsert((List<Address__c>)toUpsert, externalIdField, /*allOrNone*/false);

    }
}
system.debug(results);
```

Comment: I think I'll still encounter one more issue with this, I wont be able to call `toUpsert` after the switch case. But I still need to do processing of the failed records by comparing the `toUpsert` to `results`.

Comment: You can reference your original list (which I renamed to `dynamic` records. It has the same records in the same order.

Answer (score 3):

Why not declare a generic SobjectList outside the switch case statement?

```
List<Sobject> listSobject = new List<Sobject>();
switch on objectName {
    when 'Account' {

        for(Account dynObject : (List<Account>)lstObjects) {
            listSobject.add(dynObject);
        }
    }
    when 'Contact' {

        for(Contact dynObject : (List<Contact>)lstObjects) {
            listSobject.add(dynObject);
        }

    }
}

if(listSobject instanceOf List<Account>){
    upsert (List<Account>)listSobject;
}else if(listSobject instanceOf List<Contact>){
    upsert (List<Contact>)listSobject;
}
system.debug(listSobject);
```

Comment: I need to use this within a Database.Upsert which must have a concrete sObject defined, using the code above will not work.

Comment: @DeploymentFailure why not use instanceOf keyword to see if its list of account or Contact. Btw it looks like http://xyproblem.info/ . Can you edit the question what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I have updated my question.

Comment: I need to use Database.Upsert so that I can look at the results to determine if there are any failures, if I were to swap your upsert line with Database.upsert I am left with the same issue at the beginning where I cannot access the results outside of the IF statement.

Answer (score 2):

This code:

```
SObject[] sobs = [select Id, Name from Contact limit 5];
Database.upsert(sobs, Contact.Id, true);
```

generates the error:

> Upsert with a field specification requires a concrete SObject type

and this code does not:

```
SObject[] sobs = [select Id, Name from Contact limit 5];
Database.upsert((Contact[]) sobs, Contact.Id, true);
```

which is pretty surprising; I guess the compiler injects the static type of `sobs` in some way rather than the method internally looking at the type of `sobs` at runtime.

So if you want to use that method, you are stuck with having explicitly types.

Comment: This is only true, when using the AllOrNone command.

Comment: Those poor SOBs.

Comment: @DeploymentFailure Yeah might be limited to that method but the error message suggests that it is having the field specification that triggers the need for the type.

Answer (score 0):

OK so I was able to complete this using the following:

```
    global Database.UpsertResult[] results;

    // execute method.....

    Schema.SObjectField f = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(objectName).getDescribe().fields.getMap().get(extKey);
    List<sObject> toUpsert = (List<sObject>)Type.ForName('List<' + objectName  + '>').newInstance();
    for(sObject dynObject : lstObjects) {
        toUpsert.add(dynObject);
    }

    if(toUpsert instanceOf List<Account>){
        results = Database.upsert((List<Account>)toUpsert, f, false);
    } else if(toUpsert instanceOf List<Contact>){
        results = Database.upsert((List<Contact>)toUpsert, f, false);
    }

    system.debug(toUpsert);
    system.debug(results);
```

Comment: You don't need to do the dynamic cast at all. It adds nothing here. also your `if`/`else` chain is functionally equivalent to what Pranay and I recommended.